# Always log me into my favorite chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

The way I'm using the favorite system of chat.SE is that every one of the rooms I have in my favorite list is a room I want to be online in when I'm logged into chat. It's six rooms where I want to see if anything is happening, and when I'm logged into chat at all, I want to be logged into all of these rooms.

Now, there is a convenient button to rejoin my favorite rooms when I'm logged into only one chat room. The problem with that solution is that it doesn't appear when I'm logged into more than one room. This is a pretty common situation, I often have two chats open in different tabs. And when I suspend the computer and start it later, I'll get logged into those two rooms automatically, but I won't get the option to rejoin all my favorite rooms.

I'm not sure how other users use the favorite system, so my request to always log me into all of my favorite rooms might not be useful for everyone. But I'd like to have a way to keep me logged into all of those rooms, maybe some option in my chat profile. Another idea would be to always display the button to log into all favorite rooms, even if I'm in more than one room. But that option also might annoy some users that use chat in a different way than I do.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://i.stack.imgur.com/VVVpW.png

Comment: I know that I can get there this way, but I don't ever have the chat overview page open for long, only the actual chat rooms. So it's more like "all rooms"->"favorite"->"rejoin all" and then closing the additional tab I just opened that way. And then I reload the chat tab to get it to display the last line of all the chat rooms I'm in. This is probably a feature that is only interesting to a small minority, but if I'm logged into chat at all, I'd like to be logged into *all* my rooms.

Answer (score 5):

> Another idea would be to always display the button to log into all favorite rooms, even if I'm in more than one room. But that option also might annoy some users that use chat in a different way than I do

Yes please that is just what I would like. Ideally the button should appear if I am not logged in to one or more of my favourite rooms - perhaps labelled "rejoin *other* favorite rooms"

Answer (score 3):

Well, what I do is this:

- Open https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=favorite&sort=active, which is bookmarked
- Gaze over the chatrooms, seeing which ones have updates
- Open all the chatrooms with stuff that I haven't seen (since they show who last spoke and when) in new tabs
- click the "rejoin all" button

However, I do see the need for this, which is why I've written a bookmarklet:

```
 javascript:$.post( '/chats/join/favorite',{quiet:true,immediate:true,fkey:fkey().fkey},function(){});
```

Userscript coming up soon.

Answer (score 3):

I use favorite rooms as quasi-bookmarks -- rooms I want to keep track of but don't necessarily want to use regularly.  Because of this, I never use the "rejoin all" button.  It sounds like you're looking for a way for that button to be more readily available, which sounds like a good idea, but *automatically* rejoining rooms on login would break the "bookmark" use case, so please don't do that.  Joining a room should be a deliberate action, either for a specific room or through a "rejoin all" button.

I especially wouldn't want to automatically join a bunch of rooms on my phone; the mobile chat site can be problematic.

Comment: it could certainly be a preference, a per-room setting or an entirely separate feature.

Comment: @MadScientist I think your "another idea" of making the button always available is sound and, I hope, not too hard.

Comment: The mobile chat site *is* problematic ... the flag button is right besides the reply to this comment button, which is a bit dangerous IMHO

Comment: @DarkCygnus I think you're describing the "new" mobile chat UI.  I'm still using the old one because of accessibility problems in the new one.  They made a new one because the old one is full of (other) problems.  Can't win...